# Handling usage of shortcut with epstopdf

Tags: pdf, miktex, eps, epstopdf

On windows I have a problem when the source file is on a directory that is a shortcut.

This problem occurs with with MikTex (MiKTeX EPS-to-PDF Converter 2.9.7229 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)) as well as with Tex Live (Sorry I don't have the version information from epstopdf, but This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)).

I have the directory `Path_original` with a shortcut called `Path` to this directory (for the tests they are both in the current directory). On the `Path_original` dirctory there is the file `an_eps.eps`

The command:

```
epstopdf "Path/an_eps.eps" "--outfile=Path/an_eps.pdf"
```

gives the error message (on the console):

```
Sorry, but epstopdf did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\epstopdf.log
```

and in the log file:

```
2020-05-10 15:40:03,882+0200 INFO  epstopdf - starting with command line: epstopdf Path/an_eps.eps --outfile=Path/an_eps.pdf
2020-05-10 15:40:03,882+0200 FATAL epstopdf - The input file does not exist.
2020-05-10 15:40:03,882+0200 FATAL epstopdf - The input file does not exist.
2020-05-10 15:40:03,882+0200 FATAL epstopdf - Info:
2020-05-10 15:40:03,882+0200 FATAL epstopdf - Source:
2020-05-10 15:40:03,882+0200 FATAL epstopdf - Line: 0
```

whilst

```
epstopdf "Path_original/an_eps.eps" "--outfile=Path_original/an_eps.pdf"
```

succeeds without problems

The way of addressing the directory is out of my control i.e. the user of the (doxygen) package decides where the files reside (it is however possible that I modify doxygen slightly to address this problem).

Is there a solution inside epstopdf or outside epstopdf for this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by a shortcut? How has it been created?

Comment: On windows I went to the file explorer, clicked "Path_original" to select to directory, right clicked the directory name `Path_original`, got the pop-up menu and selected "Create Shortcut", got the name `Path_original - Shortcut`, renamed this to `Path`.

Comment: MiKTeX does not follow file/folder shortcuts (aka shell links). You can instead create a "directory junction": `mklink /J Path Path_original`

Comment: Thanks @ChristianSchenk my first though was what is a "directory junction"? so I read up on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions#junctions but I don't see how I can create such a junction an dafter that I saw that you also gave an example. I tested it and for my situation it worked (please create an answer for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MiKTeX does not follow file/folder shortcuts (aka shell links). You can instead create a "directory junction":

```
mklink /J Path Path_original
```

A directory junction is similar to a symbolic link but works only for directories.